# How to give folder permissions inside a docker container Folder

Tags: docker, permissions, dockerfile, permission-denied

I am creating a folder inside my Dockerfile and I want to give it a write permission. But I am getting permission denied error when I try to do it

```
FROM python:2.7
RUN pip install Flask==0.11.1 
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash admin
USER admin
COPY app /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod 777 /app
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

My error is

```
PS C:\Users\Shivanand\Documents\Notes\Praneeth's work\Flask> docker build -t 
shivanand3939/test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  209.9kB
Step 1/8 : FROM python:2.7
---> 8a90a66b719a
Step 2/8 : RUN pip install Flask==0.11.1
---> Using cache
---> 6dc114bd7cf1
Step 3/8 : RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash admin
---> Using cache
---> 1cfdb6eea7dc
Step 4/8 : USER admin
---> Using cache
---> 27c5e8b09f15
Step 5/8 : COPY app /app
---> Using cache
---> 5d628573b24f
Step 6/8 : WORKDIR /app
---> Using cache
---> 351e19a5a007
Step 7/8 : RUN chmod 777 /app
---> Running in aaad3c79e0f4
**chmod: changing permissions of ‘/app’: Operation not permitted
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod 777 /app' returned a non-zero code: 1**
```

How can I give write permissions to app folder inside my Docker container

Comment: The problem is that `ADD/COPY` after `USER` doesn't use the new user id as the owner of the files added to the container - even though that is what the informed user would expect. Using `--chown` as so-random-dude suggested, is the fix that shouldn't have been needed if Docker developers knew what they were doing.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I guess you are switching to user "admin" which doesn't have the ownership to change permissions on /app directory. Change the ownership using "root" user. Below Dockerfile worked for me -

```
FROM python:2.7
RUN pip install Flask==0.11.1 
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash admin
COPY app /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN chown -R admin:admin /app
RUN chmod 755 /app
USER admin
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

PS - Try to get rid of "777" permission. I momentarily tried to do it in above Dockerfile.

Comment: Docker images use different distros of Linux. Some of the Linux does not have command useradd. In my case, I had to use adduser to make it work.

Comment: This solution is w.r.t docker image `python:2.7` which has `useradd` binary. Anyway, I am glad that this answer helped you in some way.

Comment: I don't think this will work for unprivileged images. In fact it returns `Operation not permitted`

Comment: `docker container create  -v /home/python:/app `    no permission /app,

Comment: Also note: `chown` and `chmod` might have an impact on the overall image size: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30085621)

Answer (score 27):

As the Other user already pointed out, move `USER admin` to a later step

```
FROM python:2.7
RUN pip install Flask==0.11.1 
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash admin
COPY --chown=admin:admin app /app
WORKDIR /app
USER admin
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

**For versions [release v17.09.0-ce](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/releases/tag/v17.09.0-ce) and newer** you can use the optional flag `--chown=<user>:<group>` with either the `ADD` or `COPY` commands.

For example

```
COPY --chown=<user>:<group> <hostPath> <containerPath>
```

The documentation for the --chown flag is documented on [Dockerfile Reference page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add).

Answer (score 0):

On line two, after `FROM ...`, adding one line:

```
USER root
```

This will give you the power of root user.

Answer (score 0):

Running the docker image from a root user is the bad practise!
e.g. :
Add a custom user and use command to extend permissions

```
RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S 1000 && adduser -u 1001 -S 1000 -G 1000
```

Comment: Could you explain this more?  Right now in my container users (jovyan) can only r/w to /home/jovyan.  I want the user to also have r/w to a separate folder /analyst.  How does the above allow such a thing?  Right now in docker-compose I use user:root and GRANT_SUDO: "yes" ... which allows r/w anywhere and so is sub-optimal