# How to change permission of a folder to 777 in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, permissions, dockerfile, file-permissions, permission-denied

I have a project directory like this:

```
|-var/www
|-docker-compose.yml
|-app
|--uploads
|---photos
|-Dockerfile
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
myapp:
    build:
      context: myfolder
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: flask
    image: api/v1:01
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      APP_ENV: "prod"
      APP_DEBUG: "False"
      APP_PORT: 5000
    volumes:
      - appdata:/var/www
```

**What I want:** 
I want to change `app/uploads/photos` this folder's permission to `777`.This is an upload folder,so user can upload to this folder.

My `Dockerfile` now is look like this:

```
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine3.9

ENV GROUP_ID=1000 \
    USER_ID=1000

WORKDIR /var/www/
ADD . /var/www/

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev ncurses-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN addgroup -g $GROUP_ID www
RUN adduser -D -u $USER_ID -G www www -s /bin/sh

USER www

EXPOSE 5000
```

After looking in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45972608/4332049),In order to achieve what I want,I tried below:

```
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine3.9

ENV GROUP_ID=1000 \
    USER_ID=1000

WORKDIR /var/www/
ADD . /var/www/

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev ncurses-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN addgroup -g $GROUP_ID www
RUN adduser -D -u $USER_ID -G www www -s /bin/sh

RUN chown -R www:www /var/www
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/uploads
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/uploads/photos


USER www

EXPOSE 5000
```

But seems like the `chmod` command in my dockerfile is not taking effect.Cause whenever I upload some files to `app/uploads/photos` in my code,my `nginx` server keep getting this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/uploads/photos/myfilename.png'
```

Somebody please help.Please provide a solution for how to change the permission of a folder in `Dockerfile`.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to change the permission of `/var/www/uploads` after build the container and the container is running by doing below:

```
docker exec -it myapp /bin/sh
```

then run

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/uploads
```

What I get is `chmod: /var/www/uploads: Operation not permitted`

Therefore I suspect the this error will also happened when the docker is building,then according to [this answer from serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/641282/463850), I tried to modify the dockerfile to this:

```
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine3.9


ENV GROUP_ID=1000 \
    USER_ID=1000

WORKDIR /var/www/
ADD . /var/www/

USER root
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/uploads

RUN addgroup -g $GROUP_ID www
RUN adduser -D -u $USER_ID -G www www -s /bin/sh

USER www

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev ncurses-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


EXPOSE 5000
```

But it still doesnt work.Look like my above approach is also wrong.Cause I already run in root in the dockerfile.But at the same time,when I access the container in host using docker exec,also getting Operation not permitted.

I am very new in Docker.Just cant figure it out how to get this done.

**What I hope to know:**

1) How to change the folder var/www/uploads to permission 777?

2) What is the problem causing I cant change the permission from my approach?

3) What is the better way to achieve this? (If any)

Comment: Prhaps it is a dublette of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972608/how-to-give-folder-permissions-inside-a-docker-container-folder ? Switch User to admin:admin

Comment: How are you running the container?  If you're mounting a host directory over the image content (`docker run -v` option or Docker Compose `volumes:` option) then nothing you do in the Dockerfile will matter, it will all get hidden.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have a `docker-compose.yml` as well. the volume is defined there..I upload that as well

Comment: With that setup the contents of the `appdata` named volume will hide everything the Dockerfile sets up in that directory tree.  You'll need to change permissions after container startup, or set the container to run as a user who can access the volume content.

Comment: @DavidMaze can you give me an example for how to that or what is the better to do that? Cause i totally new in docker..

Comment: Since you're already `COPY` the application code into your image, you don't need to overwrite it at runtime.  I'd recommend deleting the `volumes:` block from your `docker-compose.yml`, and then the permission settings in your Dockerfile will be visible.

Comment: @DavidMaze so u mean when I delete the `volumes:` block form `docker-compose.yml`,then the `chmod` in `dockerfile` will become work?