Docker: permission denied when trying to run a golang binary
I'm trying to make a very basic app run using Docker with Docker compose.
My dockerfile:
FROM golang:1.22.4-bullseye

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg \
    && mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings

WORKDIR /app

RUN go install go.uber.org/mock/mockgen@latest && \
    go install github.com/air-verse/air@latest


RUN git config --global --add safe.directory /app

CMD ["air", "-c", ".air.toml"]

My Docker compose file:
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - 'dev.env'
    ports:
      - "443"
      - "8080"
    extra_hosts:
        - "local.invoicer.com:127.0.0.1"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - invoicer_mod_cache:/go/pkg/mod

volumes:
  invoicer_mod_cache:

My .air.toml file:
# Config file for [Air](https://github.com/cosmtrek/air) in TOML format

# Working directory
# . or absolute path, please note that the directories following must be under root.
root = "."
tmp_dir = "tmp"

[build]
# Array of commands to run before each build
pre_cmd = ["go mod download"]
# Just plain old shell command. You could use `make` as well.
cmd = "go build -o ./tmp/invoicer cmd/main.go"
# Array of commands to run after ^C
#post_cmd = ["echo 'hello air' > post_cmd.txt"]
# Binary file yields from `cmd`.
bin = "tmp/invoicer"
# Customize binary, can setup environment variables when run your app.
#full_bin = "./tmp/main"
full_bin = "export $(grep -v '^#' dev.env | xargs);tmp/invoicer"
# Watch these filename extensions.
include_ext = ["go", "tpl", "tmpl", "html", "js", "css", "scss", "toml"]
# Ignore these filename extensions or directories.
exclude_dir = ["bin", "tmp", "vendor", "certs", "static", "uploads"]
# Watch these directories if you specified.
include_dir = []
# Watch these files.
include_file = []
# Exclude files.
exclude_file = []
# Exclude specific regular expressions.
exclude_regex = ["_test\\.go", "mock_.*\\.go", "gomock_.*\\.go"]
# Exclude unchanged files.
exclude_unchanged = true
# Follow symlink for directories
follow_symlink = true
# This log file places in your tmp_dir.
log = "air.log"
# Poll files for changes instead of using fsnotify.
poll = false
# Poll interval (defaults to the minimum interval of 500ms).
poll_interval = 500 # ms
# It's not necessary to trigger build each time file changes if it's too frequent.
delay = 1000 # ms
# Stop running old binary when build errors occur.
stop_on_error = true
# Send Interrupt signal before killing process (windows does not support this feature)
send_interrupt = true
# Delay after sending Interrupt signal
kill_delay = 500 # nanosecond
# Rerun binary or not
rerun = false
# Delay after each executions
rerun_delay = 500
# Add additional arguments when running binary (bin/full_bin). Will run './tmp/main hello world'.
#args_bin = ["hello", "world"]

[log]
# Show log time
time = false
# Only show main log (silences watcher, build, runner)
main_only = false

[color]
# Customize each part's color. If no color found, use the raw app log.
main = "magenta"
watcher = "cyan"
build = "yellow"
runner = "green"

[misc]
# Delete tmp directory on exit
clean_on_exit = true

[screen]
clear_on_rebuild = true
keep_scroll = true


And when running docker compose -f dev.docker-compose.yaml up I'm getting /bin/sh: 1: tmp/invoicer: Permission denied
Thanks in advance!

Rather than mounting a directory, you should copy the source code, then build it

@OneCricketeer They are using air, copying instead of mounting would be useless. Mounting is needed for hot reload they just need to mount every folder except tmp.

Does this setup work without Docker?  (What benefits are you hoping to get from Docker here?)  It seems like you might need to go build cmd the entire Go package, and not the individual main.go file.

I'm really sorry fellas: the problem in the end was my own stupidity: the main.go file with the main() function had a package cmd instead of package main. I'll take a piece of hot iron and mark myself like cattle on my hands so I see everyday that the main function should have a package main

Its better to create an user inside the Docker container solely for the running the application. From this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45973108/22757599
FROM golang:1.22.4-bullseye

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg \
    && mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings

WORKDIR /app

RUN go install go.uber.org/mock/mockgen@latest && \
    go install github.com/air-verse/air@latest


RUN git config --global --add safe.directory /app

# answer starts right in here
#
# add myself as user, change shell if you want
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash caner
# give myself permission for the entire app folder, you may want to limit this.
# leave it as it is if you dont want to hassle.
RUN chown -R caner:caner /app
# original answer does this step, but I dont recommend it, as your app just works fine without giving every user Read and Write permissions to the app folder.
# RUN chmod 755 /app
#
# switch to me
USER caner
# and magic time
CMD ["air", "-c", ".air.toml"]

Replace caner with the user you want to create. It is not recommended to run the applications or anything as it is without an user, because you are running it as sudo by default.
dump-app-1  |    ____    __
dump-app-1  |   / __/___/ /  ___
dump-app-1  |  / _// __/ _ \/ _ \
dump-app-1  | /___/\__/_//_/\___/ v4.12.0
dump-app-1  | High performance, minimalist Go web framework
dump-app-1  | https://echo.labstack.com
dump-app-1  | ____________________________________O/_______
dump-app-1  |                                     O\
dump-app-1  | ⇨ http server started on [::]:132

ding ding

Thanks! I just added the snippet and I'm still getting the same result :(

That is interesting. Can you remove the bind of /app folder as volume in here     volumes:       - .:/app       - invoicer_mod_cache:/go/pkg/mod, maybe, with a huge a's like, maaaaaaaybe, something is interfering with the tmp folder inside your app folder (not docker container, literally your folder), changing the permissions for the invoicer binary? Air will reload whenever there is a code change or binary change and binding the binary on your own computer to the docker container might be wonky.

if I remove the /app in volumes it complains: open .air.toml: no such file or directory

Do it like this, only bind the necessary files and folders. Like -.air.toml:/app/.air.toml, for cmd folder, -cmd:/app/cmd etc. Only bind the necessary ones, bind everything except tmp

I'm really sorry have you lose your time, because in the end the problem was that the main.go file with the main() function had a package cmd instead of package main

glad you solved it matey
